# How do I determine overcurrent protection for a transformer?

Tags: electrical-engineering

What is the required: an overcurrent protection for a 3phase, 150kVA, 277/480V-120/208V transformer. With an expected load of 20a mps (3 phase 208v).

Comment: 1) Your question is too broad, be more specific. 2) It may be more on-topic on the https://electronics.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Btw, this site works much better, if you actually try to determine it, and ask a question if you find a problem.